# Formato de Numero con Decimales php

Tags: php

hago el siguiente filtro al valor enviado 3.5

```
$prd_PorcentajeRF = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prd_PorcentajeRF', 
FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

Y después del filtro muestra 4 o 35, como puedo solucionarlo? Gracias

Comment: Deberías mostrar el código que tienes en la función `filter_input`

Comment: filter_input es una función de php ´http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php´

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función de php [number_format](http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php) para convertir el número con puntos a decimales.

ejemplo:

```
$numero = 3.5;
$numero_coma = number_format($numero);
```

salida:

> 3,5

Answer (score 0):

El filtro esta correcto, el problema estaba en la base de datos donde el tipo de dato estaba como Decimal 10,0, lo cambie e 12,2 y ya se muestra el valor correctamente. Gracias por sus comentarios.